# What is the iPlanet 6.1 sp 17 download link?

Tags: oracle, download, iplanet

I have looked all over oracle iPlanet Download site they only have iPlanet 7 avaliable for download. I cannot seem to find the download url for iPlanet 6.1 sp17 or 16.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download it from the public site. You need a support contract and access to My Oracle Support. Note 1326069.1 has download links for those patches, and links to other areas for even older versions.